# Function that returns either day or number depending on parameter - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

I need a function that returns a number when you send in a day (ex. "friday"), and a day when you send in a number (ex. "06"). The function should get the parameter containing either a number or day-string. I tried making a switch, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
function dayPick(day) {

    let value;

    switch (day) {
        case "friday" || "05":
            if (day === "friday") {
                value = "05";
            } else {
                value = "friday"
            }

            break;
        case "saturday" || "06":
            if (day === "saturday") {
                value = "06";
            } else {
                value = "saturday";
            }

            break;
        case "sunday" || "07":
            if (day === "sunday") {
                value = "07";
            } else {
                value = "sunday";
            }

            break;
    }

    return value;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is a bit redundant to check if the input is `"friday"` or `"05"` once and then also check which one it is to return two completely different things. Instead you should probably have `case "friday"` and `case "05"` as separate things. It would probably be better if you separate the logic in different functions, too - having one that gives widely different results is a bit strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you check this

```
if (day === ("friday" || "05")) {}
```

which checks only for the string `'friday'`, because `'friday'` is a truthy value and the check is with strict equal.

Better you use a check for one value, like this

```
switch (day) {
    case "friday":
        value = "05";
        break;
    case "05":
        value = "friday";
        break;
    case "saturday":
        value = "06";
        break;
    case "06":
        value = "saturday";
        break;
    case "sunday":
        value = "07";
        break;
    case "07":
        value = "sunday";
        break;
}
```

Or an object, like

```
var values = { 
    friday: "05",
    "05": "friday",
    saturday: "06",
    "06": "saturday",
    sunday: "07",
    "07": "sunday"
};
```

Usage

```
value = values[day];
```

Answer (score 2):

How about an approach like this?

```
function dayPick(day) {
    var days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];
    if (isNaN(day)) {
        // Day is literal
        return days.indexOf(day) + 1;
    } else {
        // Day is numeric
        return days[day-1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function getDay(dayOrNum) {
  const week = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed','thur','fri','sat','sun'];
  
if (typeof dayOrNum === 'number') {
  return week[dayOrNum - 1];
} else {
  return week.indexOf(dayOrNum) + 1;
}
}

console.log(getDay(1)); // output 'mon'
console.log(getDay('mon')); //output 1
```